# Do beacons give buffs to friendly mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do friendly Iron Golems, Snow Golems, Dogs or similar benefit from beacon buffs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No**. Beacons only affect players. They have no effect on other mobs, passive or otherwise.

Comment: Would be kinda overpowered if you could heal your dogs and iron golems with your beacon :D